# Homotopy of Unitary  sphere  in a  Banach space and finite dimensional  spheres   

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let  $E$  be  a  Banach  space, $X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be   a  numerable  collection  of 
finite  dimensional  subspaces  $X_1\subset X_2$ with  dimension 
tending  to  infinity, denote  by  $S^n$  the unit  sphere  in $X_n$ .
Denote  by  $X$ the  union  of  the   $S^n$  and  let  Y  be the 
completion  of  the  union  $\cup X_n$   in the  ambient  norm  in  E.

Is  there  a (weak?)  retraction, homotopy  equivalence or  domination
between  X and  the  unitary  sphere  in $Y$?
Notice  that $Y$  is  not  a  CW  complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is well-known that both of $X$ and $Y$ are contractible (hence they are homotopy equivalent, this should answer your question). Notice that $Y$ is exactly the set of unit vectors of $E$.

To see that $X$ is contractible consider the map $H : X \times [0, 1] \to X$ defined by $$H((x_1, \dots, x_n, 0,\dots), t) = {(t, (1-t) x)\over \text{Norm(t, (1-t) x)}},$$ which is a homotopy between $\text{id}_X$ and a constant (a basis of $\bigcup_i X_i$ is understood).

To see that $Y$ is contractible, let's show that in fact $Y$ is homeomorphic to $E$. This can be addressed by considering the map $f: E \to E \oplus \Bbb R$ defined by $$f(x) = {(x, \|x\| - 1)\over \text{Norm}(x, \|x\| - 1)}.$$ This map gives a homeomorphism between $E$ and the unit sphere of $E \oplus \Bbb R$, which in turn should be homeomorphic to $Y$.